# How to repetitively run a function until it returns true or timeout?

Tags: go

I have a function `checkSuccess()` which return true if the task have finished.

I'd like to call `checkSuccess()` every 1 second and break until it return `true` or timeout.

What I'm having now is to use a goroutine to run a for loop, in which I call `checkSuccess()` every 1 second. And in the main process, I use `time.After` to check if the whole checking duration has passed timeout.

```
func myfunc (timeout time.Duration) {

    successChan := make(chan struct{})
    timeoutChan := make(chan struct{})

    // Keep listening to the task.
    go func() {
        for {
            select {
            // Exit the forloop if the timeout has been reached
            case <-timeoutChan:
                return
            default:
            }
            // Early exit if task has succeed.
            if checkSuccess() {
                close(successChan)
                return
            }
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }
    }()

    // Once timeout, stop listening to the task.
    select {
    case <-time.After(timeout):
        close(timeoutChan)
        return 
    case <-successChan:
        return
    }

    return
}
```

It actually has achieved my goal, but I found it very tedious. Is there any better (shorter) way to write it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need a separate goroutine or channels:

```
func myfunc (timeout time.Duration) {
   ticker:=time.NewTicker(time.Second)
   defer ticker.Close()
   to:=time.NewTimer(timeout)
   defer to.Stop()
   for {
      select {
         case <-to.C:
           return // timeout
         case <-ticker:
           if checkSuccess() {
             return
           }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Why `<-to.C`? ...

Comment: @zerkms, https://pkg.go.dev/time@go1.17.6#Timer.Stop

Comment: "To ensure the channel is empty after a call to Stop" --- why do you need it in this case? What does it change?

Comment: Thanks @BurakSerdar! also want to ask if I don't want to specify the frequency (here it's once/s), just use a naive for loop to call `checkSuccess()`, how to implement that? Thanks!

Comment: @zerkms, you are right, it doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @IsaIkari, that will busy-loop calling `checkSuccess`. You can do that by calling `checkSuccess()` in `default` case.

Comment: Even though I already upvoted, there is potentially one improvement too: `defer to.Stop()`  right after initialisation instead of calling it right before the return

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using `context.Context` in cases like this, so that the utility function can more easily be adapted to a variety of real world scenarios.

I would also return something, maybe `error`, e.g. from `ctx.Err()` or the `bool`, to give some feedback to the caller (the caller may decide to discard it anyway):

```
func tryFunc(ctx context.Context, f func() bool) bool {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    defer ticker.Stop()
    for {
        select {
        case <-ctx.Done():
            return false
        case <-ticker.C:
            if b := f(); b {
                return b
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Playground: https://go.dev/play/p/Iz_urEkBMIi

PS: make sure the context **has** a timeout. `context.Background()` doesn't

Comment: `d, ok := ctx.Deadline()` is handy to check if a context has an expiration.

Comment: It's unclear from the question if this applies, but I feel the "success" polling function should probably take a `ctx` too, if possible.